# difference between sklearn.lda.LDA() and sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-analysis, data-science, linear-discriminant

In duration of reading about LinearDiscriminantAnalysis using python , I had got two different methods to implement it which are available here ,
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html#sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis

In these method  the signature is here ,

```
sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(solver=’svd’, shrinkage=None, priors=None, n_components=None, store_covariance=False, tol=0.0001)
```

Now again i found one more method with same kind of signature , which is available here ,

http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.lda.LDA.html

```
sklearn.lda.LDA(solver='svd', shrinkage=None, priors=None, n_components=None, store_covariance=False, tol=0.0001)
```

I just wanted to know that what is difference between both . which method we should use in projects and why ?

Comment: If you want to be sure, click on "[source]" for each and check that the source codes are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation they are available here and as mentioned by @Atto

```
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html
```

and

```
http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.lda.LDA.html
```

Now basically LDA is basically an older version and LinearDiscriminateAnalys is newly updated and  is preferred

Answer (score 1):

They seem to be exactly the same (I assume LDA is short for LinearDiscriminantAnalysis) as shown by the docs:

> http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html

and

> http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.lda.LDA.html

As these pages are identical, even up to the sample code, except for the fact that all references of `sklearn.lda.LDA` have been replaced by `sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis`, I don't think it matters which one you use at all.

I hope this answers your question, they're the same!

Comment: I know that both are same but at production level which methods to use and why?